# How to animate images on page scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a page where I have few images. I would like to know how to animate images as a user scrolls down the page and the images become visible? Take a look at this page: http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Divi

As you scroll down, each image animates - (fall down, slide in) + Fade. What is this effect called and how it can be achieved? Can it be done with pure CSS3 or JS is also required?

Thanks.

Comment: css transitions is what u need

Comment: @monners: What is up with people here on stackoverflow? I am just asking for ideas. If you don't have anything to contribute, please refrain from commenting. No one asked you to do work for me. If you have a such a problem, go troll somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I found Skrollr.js to be the best tool for on scroll animations.

Check our these two tutorials to get you started with Skrollr:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)

[EDIT] Or you could use [scrollReveal.js](http://scrollrevealjs.org/), it does what it says - reveals elements as you scroll down the page.

Comment: I don't think what I am looking is parallax scrolling. I am looking into more like lazyload with animation. Thanks though.

Comment: Oh ok, then you need to use something like [Inview.js](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) and CSS3 animations. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/jU6m9/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically Javascript is needed here in order to follow the user scrolling down, and animating when he gets to specific position.

I highly recommending using GreenSock animations:
http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/

You can read more about it here:
http://codeaway.info/parallax-and-scrolling-control-of-tweens-with-greensock-ap-js/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. It looks like a lot of work some a simple thing. But again, I haven't read it completely. Going to check now.